# kalman filter with python in function EuclideanDistTracker()

Tags: python, opencv, object, tracking, kalman-filter

I have a car tracking project with yolov4 and it works with EuclideanDistTracker for tracking and counting.

but sometimes, it lost the cars and found them wih new count id so the counting is wrong.

so, I think my problem is in tracking. I want to increase the accuracy with tracking. so I research it and found kalman filter.

I tried to add kalman to my code but I couldn't.

How can I add kalman filter in my project.

here is the code I used:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import time
import math    

class EuclideanDistTracker:
    def __init__(self):
        # Store the center positions of the objects
        self.center_points = {}
        # Keep the count of the IDs
        # each time a new object id detected, the count will increase by one
        self.id_count = 1


    def update(self, objects_rect):
        # Objects boxes and ids
        objects_bbs_ids = []

        # Get center point of new object
        for rect in objects_rect:
            x, y, w, h = rect
            cx = (x + x + w) // 2
            cy = (y + y + h) // 2

            # Find out if that object was detected already
            same_object_detected = False
            for id, pt in self.center_points.items():
                dist = math.hypot(cx - pt[0], cy - pt[1])

                if dist < 25:
                    self.center_points[id] = (cx, cy)
                    #print(self.center_points)
                    objects_bbs_ids.append([x, y, w, h, id])
                    same_object_detected = True
                    break

            # New object is detected we assign the ID to that object
            if same_object_detected is False:
                self.center_points[self.id_count] = (cx, cy)
                objects_bbs_ids.append([x, y, w, h, self.id_count])
                self.id_count += 1

        # Clean the dictionary by center points to remove IDS not used anymore
        new_center_points = {}
        for obj_bb_id in objects_bbs_ids:
            _, _, _, _, object_id = obj_bb_id
            center = self.center_points[object_id]
            new_center_points[object_id] = center

        # Update dictionary with IDs not used removed
        self.center_points = new_center_points.copy()
        return objects_bbs_ids
 
Toplam_filtered =[]
KF = KalmanFilter(0.1, 1, 1, 1, 0.1,0.1)
     
# Create tracker object
tracker = EuclideanDistTracker()

# Load Yolo
net = cv.dnn.readNet("yolov4-tiny_best.weights", "yolov4-tiny.cfg")

net.setPreferableBackend(cv.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA)
           
classes = []
with open("obj.names", "r") as f:
    classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    
layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

# Loading video
cap = cv.VideoCapture("test2.mp4")
cap.set(3, 1280) # set video widht
cap.set(4, 720) # set video height

font = cv.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL
starting_time = time.time()
frame_id = 0
toplam = 0
print("\033[H\033[J") 
say=0
while True:
    # Get frame
    _, frame = cap.read()
   
    
    frame_id += 1
    if frame_id % 2 != 0:
        continue
    
    height, width, channels = frame.shape

    # Detecting objects
    blob = cv.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 0.00261, (416, 416), (0, 0, 0), True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    
    outs = net.forward(output_layers)
    
    result = []
    boxes = []
    liste = []
    for out in outs:
        for detection in out:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.3:
                # Object detected
                center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
                center_y = int(detection[1] * height)
                w = int(detection[2] * width)
                h = int(detection[3] * height)

                # Rectangle coordinates
                x = int(center_x - w / 2)
                y = int(center_y - h / 2)
                
                if 75 < center_x < 1150 and 300 < center_y < 500:
                    boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                
        
    boxes_ids = tracker.update(boxes)

    
     
    eklenecekler = []
    filtered =[]
   
    
    for i in range(len(boxes_ids)):
        if boxes_ids[i][4] not in eklenecekler:
            eklenecekler.append(boxes_ids[i][4])
            filtered.append(boxes_ids[i])
            
   
    for box_id in filtered:
            x, y, w, h, id = box_id
            cv.rectangle(frame, (x,y+h-20), (x+30,y+h), (0,0,255),-1) #köşe kırmızı kare
            cv.putText(frame, str(id), (x , y + h-5), font, 1, (255,255,255), 1) # count yazısı
            cv.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0,0,0), 2) #araç kareleri
   
            (kalx, kaly) = KF.predict()
            
            print(kalx, kaly)
            cv.rectangle(frame, (int(kalx), int(kaly)), (int(kalx + w), int(kaly + h)), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    
    Toplam_filtered = [*Toplam_filtered, *filtered]

    # For fps
    elapsed_time = time.time() - starting_time
    fps = frame_id / elapsed_time
    
    
    
    #total car count
    try:
        _,_,_,_,value = max(filtered, key=lambda item: item[4])
        if value > toplam:
            toplam = value
    except:
        pass
     
    #mavi çizgi
    cv.line(frame,(0,350),(1280,350),(255,0,0),2)
    
    #Some texts
    cv.putText(frame, "FPS: " + str(round(fps, 2)), (5, 156), font, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv.putText(frame, "NAZIM CORAKLI", (600, 70), font, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv.putText(frame, str(toplam), (1200, 70), font, 2, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    
    #Final
    cv.imshow("Awsome Car Counting", frame)
    
    # Press 'ESC' for exiting video
    k = cv.waitKey(1) & 0xff 
    if k == 27:
        break
    if k == ord('p'):
        cv.waitKey(-1) #wait until any key is pressed

cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

and here is kalman filter code I found:

```
'''
    File name         : KalmanFilter.py
    Description       : KalmanFilter class used for object tracking
    Author            : Rahmad Sadli
    Date created      : 20/02/2020
    Python Version    : 3.7
'''

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class KalmanFilter(object):
    def __init__(self, dt, u_x,u_y, std_acc, x_std_meas, y_std_meas):
        """
        :param dt: sampling time (time for 1 cycle)
        :param u_x: acceleration in x-direction
        :param u_y: acceleration in y-direction
        :param std_acc: process noise magnitude
        :param x_std_meas: standard deviation of the measurement in x-direction
        :param y_std_meas: standard deviation of the measurement in y-direction
        """

        # Define sampling time
        self.dt = dt

        # Define the  control input variables
        self.u = np.matrix([[u_x],[u_y]])

        # Intial State
        self.x = np.matrix([[0], [0], [0], [0]])

        # Define the State Transition Matrix A
        self.A = np.matrix([[1, 0, self.dt, 0],
                            [0, 1, 0, self.dt],
                            [0, 0, 1, 0],
                            [0, 0, 0, 1]])

        # Define the Control Input Matrix B
        self.B = np.matrix([[(self.dt**2)/2, 0],
                            [0,(self.dt**2)/2],
                            [self.dt,0],
                            [0,self.dt]])

        # Define Measurement Mapping Matrix
        self.H = np.matrix([[1, 0, 0, 0],
                            [0, 1, 0, 0]])

        #Initial Process Noise Covariance
        self.Q = np.matrix([[(self.dt**4)/4, 0, (self.dt**3)/2, 0],
                            [0, (self.dt**4)/4, 0, (self.dt**3)/2],
                            [(self.dt**3)/2, 0, self.dt**2, 0],
                            [0, (self.dt**3)/2, 0, self.dt**2]]) * std_acc**2

        #Initial Measurement Noise Covariance
        self.R = np.matrix([[x_std_meas**2,0],
                           [0, y_std_meas**2]])

        #Initial Covariance Matrix
        self.P = np.eye(self.A.shape[1])

    def predict(self):
        # Refer to :Eq.(9) and Eq.(10)  in https://machinelearningspace.com/object-tracking-simple-implementation-of-kalman-filter-in-python/?preview_id=1364&preview_nonce=52f6f1262e&preview=true&_thumbnail_id=1795

        # Update time state
        #x_k =Ax_(k-1) + Bu_(k-1)     Eq.(9)
        self.x = np.dot(self.A, self.x) + np.dot(self.B, self.u)

        # Calculate error covariance
        # P= A*P*A' + Q               Eq.(10)
        self.P = np.dot(np.dot(self.A, self.P), self.A.T) + self.Q
        return self.x[0:2]

    def update(self, z):

        # Refer to :Eq.(11), Eq.(12) and Eq.(13)  in https://machinelearningspace.com/object-tracking-simple-implementation-of-kalman-filter-in-python/?preview_id=1364&preview_nonce=52f6f1262e&preview=true&_thumbnail_id=1795
        # S = H*P*H'+R
        S = np.dot(self.H, np.dot(self.P, self.H.T)) + self.R

        # Calculate the Kalman Gain
        # K = P * H'* inv(H*P*H'+R)
        K = np.dot(np.dot(self.P, self.H.T), np.linalg.inv(S))  #Eq.(11)

        self.x = np.round(self.x + np.dot(K, (z - np.dot(self.H, self.x))))   #Eq.(12)

        I = np.eye(self.H.shape[1])

        # Update error covariance matrix
        self.P = (I - (K * self.H)) * self.P   #Eq.(13)
        return self.x[0:2]
```